# Counting the sum of occurrences of a string set S in a trie T

Tags: c++, design-patterns, matching, trie, aho-corasick

I am given an already populated [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) T and a set of strings S. I am to compute the sum over the occurences of all elements of `S` in `T`. I am a bit confused as to how to go about this.

An example trie is built out of `aa`, `ab` and `bbb` and is supposed to return `9` for `S={"b","bb","bb","bbb"}`, which seems obvious when looking at the trie (`b` occurs 4 times, `bb` twice, and `bbb` once, so `4+2*2+1 = 9`), but I'm not really sure how to calculate this on a larger scale. Any help on the procedure I would have to go through is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What part gives you problem: walking the trie or counting occurrences at a node?

Comment: Mostly counting the occurrences at a node. I understand how a trie works and how to walk along it, but I'm not sure how I can catch all occurrences - For example the single "b" in "ab".